# Invalid URI: the url is too long

Tags: .net, rest, system.net.httpwebrequest

I am trying to pass data to a restful web service which receives data in JSON format. The data I am trying to GET is quite huge, I get an exception as shown below

```
request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
```

The exception is

> Invalid URI: The Uri string is too long.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: and what's the value in `url`? It should be URI like `http://yoururl`

Comment: url  = @"http://remoteserver/service?data=jsondata"

Comment: You should use `POST` for large requests.

Comment: There is a limit on the number for characters that can be sent in a get request. If you have hosted the web service try to convert it into a post request. That will be better.

Comment: I am afraid the service is hosted on a remote machine. I have no control over the web service. I can only consume the service.

Comment: Have you tried to check for json is valid or not? You can test it http://jsonlint.com/ here. If it's valid then you should check the length of the json data because i guess it may exceed the default length and causing this error.